# Fastest way to generate combinations of rows

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, postgresql

We have a table of plans and each plan has many services. We would like a fast way of **finding the combinations of plans that do not contain duplicate services but as a combinations contain certain services.**

e.g. table of plans

```
id | service_1 | service_2 | ...
---------------------------------
1  |   true    |  true     | ...
2  |   true    |  false    | ...
3  |   false   |  true     | ...
```

e.g. valid combinations containing service_1 and service_2

**UPDATE**

**If there were 2 services and I required both of them we would combine up to 2 rows (or plans) as they could contain at minimum 1 service in each.**

```
id | service_1 | service_2 | id | service_1 | service_2 |
---------------------------------------------------------
1  |   true    |  true     |NULL|    NULL   |    NULL   |
2  |   true    |  false    | 3  |    false  |    true   |
```

**UPDATE**

**It currently works by self left joining itself** with aggressive pruning or rows. The query is dynamically generated based on the number of services. It creates the permutations of valid join conditions making it not practical to post.

Currently the cost is in the order of number of plans ^ number of services.

I'm mostly interested in other ways of solving this not necessarily improvements to the current way.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Not enough information.  How many services will you specify in your search, and what number of plans are allowed to be used to answer the query?

Comment: @mitch snarky, eh? "It currently works by self left joining itself with aggressive pruning or rows." to me this adequately describes a possible current solution, and I can imagine how it could cost "number of plans ^ number of services."

Comment: @cyberkiwi: My comment was made before poster updated his question. Please get your facts straight.

Comment: @Mitch - The question (rev1) was challenging enough to attack. If you don't agree, please feel free to see the back of the question, or you could have down-voted it to see if others agree.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: That makes no sense.

Comment: @Mitch - "see the back of" = "leave". If you feel that the question was not to your liking, you can always down vote and if enough people feel the same it would go (I doubt it). Personally, the core of the question from the start seemed ok (to me).

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I'll leave when I see fit. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm with Mitch Wheat and Larry Lustig. Exactly what is being sought is unclear. Why exactly does id=3 map to id=2 and not id=1? Why doesn't id=3 show on its own row?

Comment: "finding the combinations of plans that do not contain duplicate services"

Comment: @Moriarty - Then how is it that id=2 and id=3 in your example are "duplicates"? id=2 has service1 and id=3 does not. id=2 does not have service2 and id=3 does. How do you deduce those to be duplicates?

Comment: @thomas 1 alone provides s1 and s2. 2 and 3 combine to provide s1 and s2. 1 and 3 is not a match because that provides s2 twice..

Comment: @cyberwiki - First, then why isn't 2 a match for 3 since 3 is a match for 2? Second, the term "duplicate" is a poor choice of terms. If what you are suggesting is accurate, then what is being sought is all plans which combined with the current plan will provide all services exactly once. I.e., the binary one's compliment. I.e., XOR where the result is equal to all ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work ok

Setup data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plan;
CREATE TABLE plan (id int, service1 bool, service2 bool, service3 bool);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`id`, `service1`, `service2`, `service3`) VALUES (1, 1, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`id`, `service1`, `service2`, `service3`) VALUES (2, 0, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`id`, `service1`, `service2`, `service3`) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`id`, `service1`, `service2`, `service3`) VALUES (4, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`id`, `service1`, `service2`, `service3`) VALUES (5, 0, 0, 1);
```

The query

```
select *
from plan A
left join (
    select id, service1, service2, service3 from plan
    union all
    select null, null, null, null) B on B.id > A.id or B.id is null
left join (
    select id, service1, service2, service3 from plan
    union all
    select null, null, null, null) C on C.id > B.id or C.id is null
WHERE (A.service1 + A.service2 + A.service3)
  AND (A.service1 + ifnull(B.service1,0) + ifnull(C.service1,0)) = 1
  AND (A.service2 + ifnull(B.service2,0) + ifnull(C.service2,0)) = 1
  AND (A.service3 + ifnull(B.service3,0) + ifnull(C.service3,0)) = 1
```

Result

```
id | service1 | service2 | service3 | id | service1 | service2 | service3 | id | service1 | service2 | service3
1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0
2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | 1 | 0 | 1
3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

Comment: The pattern is expanded by left join, and AND lines in the where clause, but other than that, there is no exponential/polynomial expansion of permutations to consider.

Comment: Brilliant I'll give that a go.

Comment: In case you missed it, I changed "C.id > A.id or C.id is null" to "C.id > B.id or C.id is null"

Comment: Yep, order them. Cheers for this. I'll just go test it out.

Comment: Damn. Same speed but much cleaner than the current code. Thanks very much. You will get if answer if nothing faster comes along.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, the rule by which one determines a "duplicate" is unclear. However, from the sounds of it, you are simply doing a bitwise AND.

```
With RawData As
    (
    Select 1 As id, 1 As service_1, 1 As service_2
    Union All Select 2, 1, 0
    Union All Select 3, 0, 1
    )
    , BinData As
    (
    Select A.id, A.service_1, A.service_2
        , A.service_1 * 2 + A.service_2 As Bin
    From RawData As A
    )
Select *
From BinData As F1
    Left Join BinData As F2
        On F2.id <> F1.id
            And F1.Bin & F2.Bin = 0
Order By F1.id
```

However, you will note in this solution that I get a row for id=3. For the same reason that id=3 is a "duplicate" for id=2, the reverse is also true.

If this is not correct, we need far more clarity and some better sample data that illustrates the edge cases of what is and is not a "duplicate".

**Update**

Given what cyberwiki has stated in comments, if what is being sought for each plan is another plan which when combined provide all services exactly once, then what is being sought is a binary one's compliment that will produce all 1's. We can do that by finding all plans which when XOR'd to the current plan produce all ones:

```
With RawData As
    (
    Select 1 As id, 1 As service_1, 1 As service_2
    Union All Select 2, 1, 0
    Union All Select 3, 0, 1
    )
    , BinData As
    (
    Select A.id, A.service_1, A.service_2
        , A.service_1 * 2 + A.service_2 As Bin
    From RawData As A
    )
Select *, F1.Bin ^ F2.Bin
From BinData As F1
    Left Join BinData As F2
        On F2.id <> F1.id
            And F1.Bin ^ F2.Bin = 3
Order By F1.id
```

Again, note that id=3 will show in the result because just as id=3 is perfect match for id=2, the reverse is also true.

Comment: Much appreciated Thomas. I'll attempt to shift some bits and see how it performs.